# Alternative option of for and findIndex Loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using `for` and `findIndex` to update the Totals in the main `result` variable. Is there an alternative way to rewrite this to be shorter or more readable?

```js
const payload = [
        { Id: 1, Total: 5 },
        { Id: 3, Total: 2 },
]

const result = {
    Items: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B', Total: 0},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D', Total: 0},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E', Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F', Total: 0},
    ]
}

for(const itemPayload of payload) {
    const itemIndex = result.Items.findIndex(item => item.Id === itemPayload.Id && item.Type === "Main");
    
    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
        result.Items[itemIndex].Total = itemPayload.Total;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we are creating a `Map` and then accessing it in a loop. It's much cleaner and more readable.

```js
const payload = [
  { Id: 1, Total: 5 },
  { Id: 3, Total: 2 },
]

const result = {
  Items: [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A', Total: 1, Type: "Main" },
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B', Total: 0 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C', Total: 1, Type: "Main" },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D', Total: 0 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E', Type: "Main" },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F', Total: 0 },
  ]
};


const payloadMap = payload.reduce((map, obj) => {
  map[obj.Id] = obj.Total;
  return map;
}, {});

result.Items = result.Items.map(item => {
  if (item.Type === 'Main' && payloadMap[item.Id]) {
    item.Total = payloadMap[item.Id];
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59020364/157247) already covers doing this. Please read existing answers before posting new ones, so you don't just repeat what's been done before.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the payload to a Map, then loop `result.Items` just once (instead of repeatedly via `findIndex`):

```
const payloadMap = new Map(payload.map(({Id, Total}) => [Id, Total]));
for (const item of result.Items) {
    if (item.Type === "Main") {
        const total = payloadMap.get(item.Id);
        if (total !== undefined) {
            item.Total = total;
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const payload = [
        { Id: 1, Total: 5 },
        { Id: 3, Total: 2 },
]

const result = {
    Items: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B', Total: 0},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D', Total: 0},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E', Type: "Main"},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F', Total: 0},
    ]
}

// Convert the payload to a Map:
const payloadMap = new Map(payload.map(({Id, Total}) => [Id, Total]));

// Loop through `result.Items` just once:
for (const item of result.Items) {
    if (item.Type === "Main") {
        const total = payloadMap.get(item.Id);
        if (total !== undefined) {
            item.Total = total;
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Maps are optimized for random access retrieval.

Another option is to have a Map of `type = "Main"` items in addition to the array of them in `result`, both referring to the same object, but it means that when you add/remove to/from the array, you have to add/remove from the Map as well.

Comment: If result Items is only 100 items max, there is no benefit not to use findIndex? we know node js is fast

Comment: @user88432 - That'll depend at least in part on how big `payload` is, but I assume if `result.Items` is only 100 at most, `payload` will be < 100 at most. I wouldn't think this would be a bottleneck, but of course, that depends on your app. That said, a temporary Map is simple to create and definitely more efficient. But if you want a middle ground, you could repeatedly search `payload` instead of `result.Items` as [Shubh showed in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59020369/157247).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something Like this ,if this is what you are looking for.

```js
const payload = [{
    Id: 1,
    Total: 5
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    Total: 2
  },
]

const result = {
  Items: [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Item 1 A',
      Total: 1,
      Type: "Main"
    },
    {
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Item 1 B',
      Total: 0
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Item 2 C',
      Total: 1,
      Type: "Main"
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Item 2 D',
      Total: 0
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: 'Item 3 E',
      Type: "Main"
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: 'Item 3 F',
      Total: 0
    },
  ]
}


let newdata = result.Items.map(ele => {

  if (ele.Type == "Main") {
    let payload_ = payload.find(e => e.Id == ele.Id);
    if (payload_) {

      ele.Total = payload_.Total;

    }

  }
  return ele;

})

console.log(newdata);
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this just repeaetdly searches `payload` with `find` instead of repeatedly searching `result.Items` with `findIndex`. It does have the advantage that A) You don't have to do it for *all* items because of the `type` restriction, and B) `payload` is presumably always going to be smaller than `result.Items`. But it's still repeated searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find()` method to get the first match for a selection criteria, and use `o.hasOwnProperty('Total') && obj.Id === o.Id)` as the selection criteria:

```js
    const payload = [
            { Id: 1, Total: 5 },
            { Id: 3, Total: 2 },
    ]
    
    const result = {
        Items: [
            { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
            { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B', Total: 0},
            { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C', Total: 1, Type: "Main"},
            { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D', Total: 0},
            { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E', Type: "Main"},
            { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F', Total: 0},
        ]
    }
    
    payload.forEach(obj => result.Items.find(o => (o.hasOwnProperty('Total') && obj.Id === o.Id)).Total = obj.Total) 
    
    
    console.log(result);
```